# render texts when they are out of div

Tags: css, html

I'm making a matrix rain html5 game.
But it does not render the text until the text's top css property be 0 or more. So it looks like the text appears at top instead of coming from top.
This works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.
Is there anyway to force the browser to always render the text?
TNX

Comment: Without seeing anything, we can only rely on our psychic powers. But that's forbidden on StackOverflow.

Comment: Link? Code? JSfiddle?

Comment: try text to  `z-index:9999` !!